# AngularJS and Spring Rest

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I'm using AngularJS to post a simple form to an API written with Spring boot and Rest. Every class is annotated with @RestController

My spring Controller method is as following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@Valid @RequestBody Modality modality) {
      mService.save(modality);

      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("");
}
```

HTML form:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Modality:.</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="modality" id="modality" ng-model="Modality.name" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Active:.</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="active" id="active" ng-model="Modality.active" value="" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit">Enviar</button> &nbsp;
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" /> &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Post via Angular:

```
$scope.Modality = {id: null, name: '', active: ''}
$scope.submit = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            url: "http://localhost:8080/v1/modality",
            data: $scope.modality
        }).success(function(data) {
                console.log($scope.modality);
        });
}
```

When i use angular to submit the form, i can see that the modality object is being populated with the form data, but when it arrives at spring controller, the modality object has all its attributes null and because of that, iḿ getting the following error:

```
{"status":400, "error":"Badequest",
"exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Required request body is missing: 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>
cc.sporthub.controllers.ModalityController.create(cc.sporthub.models.Modality","path":"/v1/modality"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your problem is caused by the variable name use data: $scope.Modality instead of data: $scope.modality

Comment: Try sending JSON: `data: JSON.stringify($scope.modality);`

Comment: I already tried it but got same error....

Comment: The object containing the value is `scope.Modality`. But you're sending `scope.modality`.

Comment: You're right... a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're using **scope.modality** with lower case.

The Javascript variables are case sensitive.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp